# Should I close time.After channel if waiting result from goroutine?

Tags: go, concurrency, synchronization, goroutine

Let's assume following code

```
type resultWrapper struct {
  result Result
  err    error
}

func (e executor) Execute(ctx context.Context) Result {
  ch := make(chan ResultWrapper, 1)

  go func() {
      defer close(ch)
      // base also returns type Result
      res := e.base.Execute(ctx)
      if res.IsError() {
          ch <- resultWrapper{
              result: &e.defaultResponse,
              err:    nil,
          }
          return
      }
      ch <- wrapper{
          result: &res,
          err:    nil,
      }
  }()

  select {
  case <-time.After(e.timeout):
      return e.defaultResponse
  case res := <-ch:
      return res.result
  }
}
```

My question is if I should close created by `time.After` channel in some proper way?
And I don't fully understand what will happen with goroutine calling `e.base.Execute` if I exit from main `Execute` function by timeout?

Answer (score 3):

[`time.After()`](https://pkg.go.dev/time#After) returns a receive-only channel:

```
func After(d Duration) <-chan Time
```

Which cannot be closed. Quoting from [Spec: Built-in functions: Close](https://go.dev/ref/spec#Close):

> For an argument `ch` with a [core type](https://go.dev/ref/spec#Core_types) that is a [channel](https://go.dev/ref/spec#Channel_types), the built-in function `close` records that no more values will be sent on the channel. **It is an error if `ch` is a receive-only channel.**

Documentation of `time.After()` also states:

> The underlying Timer is not recovered by the garbage collector until the timer fires. If efficiency is a concern, use NewTimer instead and call Timer.Stop if the timer is no longer needed.

So you could use [`time.NewTimer()`](https://pkg.go.dev/time#NewTimer) which you can "free" earlier using `Timer.Stop()`.

**But!** Since the operation you're calling `e.base.Execute(ctx)` already supports a context, the easiest and most idiomatic solution would be to create a new, derived context with timeout (using [`context.WithTimeout()`](https://pkg.go.dev/context#WithTimeout)):

```
func (e executor) Execute(ctx context.Context) Result {
    ctx, cancel := context.WithTimeout(ctx, e.timeout)
    defer cancel()

    res := e.base.Execute(ctx)
    if res.IsError() {
            return e.defaultResponse,
    }

    return res.result
}
```

If `e.base.Execute()` is properly implemented, it must monitor the passed context, which will be cancelled after `e.timeout`. Note the deferred `cancel()` call which will free used resources if `e.base.Execute()` should finish before `e.timeout`.